# Jenkins and SonarQube within same Docker Container

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube

Is it possible to run the Jenkins and sonarQube servers inside the same Docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not specialist in docker containers, but according to [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/), yes, it is possible to run multiple services in a same container.

In this documentation, there are two possible ways:

- Put all of your commands in a wrapper script, complete with testing and debugging information. Run the wrapper script as your CMD. This is a very naive example. First, the wrapper script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # Start the first process 
  ./my_first_process -D 
  status=$? 
  if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then   
     echo "Failed to start my_first_process: $status"   
     exit $status 
  fi

  # Start the second process     
  ./my_second_process -D 
  status=$? 
  if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "Failed to start my_second_process: $status"   
     exit $status 
  fi       
  while sleep 60; do
     ps aux |grep my_first_process |grep -q -v grep   
     PROCESS_1_STATUS=$?   
     ps aux |grep my_second_process |grep -q -v grep  
     PROCESS_2_STATUS=$?   
     if [ $PROCESS_1_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_2_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "One of the processes has already exited."
        exit 1 
     fi 
  done
  ```

  Now, the Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:latest
  COPY my_first_process my_first_process
  COPY my_second_process my_second_process
  COPY my_wrapper_script.sh my_wrapper_script.sh
  CMD ./my_wrapper_script.sh
  ```
- Or use a process manager like supervisord. This is a moderately heavy-weight approach that requires you to package supervisord and its configuration in your image (or base your image on one that includes supervisord), along with the different applications it manages. Then you start supervisord, which manages your processes for you. Here is an example Dockerfile using this approach, that assumes the pre-written supervisord.conf, my_first_process, and my_second_process files all exist in the same directory as your Dockerfile.

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:latest
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
  RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
  COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
  COPY my_first_process my_first_process
  COPY my_second_process my_second_process
  CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
  ```